# Can I start the bluetooth daemon without a USB dongle being connected?

Tags: debian, usb, bluetooth, daemon

I'm installing bluetooth for my Debian installation (non desktop) and I wonder about the daemon.

The guide states that in order to start it I have to type:

```
/etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

but really, I want to do this every time the computer starts up -- but the usb dongle is not always connected.

Can I still do it, and how do I add it (rc?) so it starts up every time?

Comment: What guide are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the daemon start on boot and it'll work just fine.  When you insert the bluetooth dongle, it'll get picked up and activated.

To make debian start the bluetooth daemon every time on boot, execute the following as root (or use sudo)

```
update-rc.d bluetooth defaults
```

-or-

```
sudo update-rc.d bluetooth defaults
```

This will install the correct symlinks into the boot system so bluetooth will be active from boot.

The rest... is up to you.